# How to prove these two statements in set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have two problems to solve :

1. If $ A \cup B = A - B $  then $ B = \varnothing $
2. If $ A - B = B - A $  then $ A = B $

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages learning, you will get much more help if you show us what you have already done. Could you edit your question with your thoughts and ideas?

Comment: ok. let me edit and write my own way to solve it.

Comment: This question appears to be inappropriate for this site because it is multiple questions in one.

Comment: Please, post only one question in one post. Posting several questions in the same post is discouraged and such questions may be put on hold, see [meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/posting-multiple-questions-as-one).

Comment: For the second question, see here:
[When is $A- B = B- A$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2118095) and
[For what conditions on sets $A$ and $B$ the statement $A - B = B - A$ holds?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1909611)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Assume that $B$ contains an element $b$ then $b\in A\cup B$ so $b\in A-B$ which means that $b\not\in B$. Contradiction.
2. Assume $ A-B\ne\varnothing$ then there's $x\in A-B=B-A$ so $x\in A$ and $x\not\in A$. Contradiction. Hence we have $A-B=\varnothing$ and then $A\subset B$. Similarly we prove that $B\subset A$.

Answer (score 1):

here: $U := A \cup B$
1. $$A \cup B = A - B \Rightarrow B\subseteq A \cup B = A \cap B^c\subseteq B^c$$

---

2. $$A - B = B - A$$ then $$B\cup(A - B)=B\cup(B - A)$$ 
   $$A \cup B =  B$$
   $$A\subseteq B $$
   in the same manner you have 
   $$B\subseteq A$$

Answer (score 0):

1. If $b\in B$ then $b\in A\cup B$ but $b\notin A-B$ so $b\notin B$ and $B$ must be empty.
2. If $A-B=B-A$ then:$$A=(A\cap B)\cup(A-B)=(A\cap B)\cup(B-A)=B$$