# For what conditions on sets $A$ and $B$ the statement $A - B = B - A$ holds?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The obvious response is $A = B$. But I came up with another response. I can't figure out what's my bias.

Lets say

- $S = A - B$
- $T = B - A$

Proving $S=T$ means proving $S \subseteq T$ and $T \subseteq S$

Let's start with $S \subseteq T$

For any $x \in S$ :

- $x \in A$
- $x \notin B$

if $S \subseteq T$, $x \in T$ and :

- $x \in B$
- $x \notin A$

There is no $x$ giving satisfaction, so $A$ and $B$ are empty.

I prove $T \subseteq S$ by symmetry

My solution is : $A = B = \emptyset$

What's wrong ?

Comment: If there is no $x$ satisfying this, it means that $S$ is empty, not $A$

Comment: Of course, the empty set is a set such as no x can satisfy its definition. Didn't see it like this. Thanks!

Comment: See also: [When is $A- B = B- A$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2118095)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us look at the flaw in your logic. We are given that $S \subset T$. Then, if $x \in S$, then $x \in A - B$, so $x \in A$, and $x \notin B$. But also, $x \in T$, which means that $x \in B$ and $x \notin A$. Hence, $x \in B$ and $x \notin B$, which is a contradiction. Hence, no such $x$ exists, so $S$ must be empty. Reversing the argument, we conclude that $T$ must be empty. In other words, $A \subset B$ and $B \subset A$, so $B=A$.

Answer (score 2):

I tried your reasoning using predicate logic.  I'm posting the answer to show an alternative way of reasoning.

So, $x \in A-B$ if $x \in A$ but $x\not\in B$.  Equivalently, $x\in B-A$ if $x \in B$ but $x \not\in A$.  Thus, $A-B = B-A$ if
\begin{equation}
\forall x : ( x \in A \wedge x\not\in B \Longleftrightarrow x\not\in A\wedge x\in B )
\end{equation}

Remember $\varphi \Longleftrightarrow \psi$ means $(\varphi \wedge \psi) \vee (\neg \varphi \wedge \neg \psi )$.  But in this case, the left term of this re-written equivalence is $x \in A \wedge x\not\in B \wedge x\not\in A\wedge x\in B$ and it is obviously impossible (equal to $\bot$), so the only possibility for $x$ is 
\begin{align}
  & \neg(x \in A \wedge x\not\in B) \wedge \neg(x\not\in A\wedge x\in B) \\
  =& (x \not\in A \vee x\in B) \wedge (x\in A\vee x\not\in B) \\
  =& (x \not\in A \wedge x\not\in B) \vee (x\in A\wedge x\in B) \vee (x \in A \wedge x\not\in A) \vee (x\not\in B\wedge x\in B) \\
  =& (x \not\in A \wedge x\not\in B) \vee (x\in A\wedge x\in B) \\
\end{align}

In other words, there are no $x$ such that $A$ contains $x$ but not $B$ or $B$ contains $x$ but not $A$.  That is, $A$ and $B$ have the same elements, i.e. $A=B$.

Comment: I don't know about predicate logic, but I had enough background to understand your response. This is very powerful, I hope I will learn predicate logic very quickly. I can't vote for your response because I'm new user but I'm very glad of it.

Comment: To be honest, I was pretty informal.  For example, I did not really defined my axioms and using them the fact that $A-B = B-A$ is equivalent to $\forall x : ...$ can be showed precisely.  Knowing formal logic can help to see what's wrong with informal logic, but don't worry, I did 5 years of university maths before learning formal logic and I survived.

Comment: Im not completely sure that the statement $x \in A \wedge x\not\in B \wedge x\not\in A\wedge x\in B$ is necessarily a contradiction, it is possibly true that $x\in A\land x\notin A$ holds if $A=\emptyset$?

Comment: If $A = \varnothing$, then there is no $x$ such that $x \in A$...  Remember, $\varphi \wedge \neg \varphi$ is always equal to $\bot$ and $x \not\in A$ is a nice way to write $\neg( x\in A )$.

Comment: @Masacroso This is exactly the mistake I did. Writing $x \in A$ implies $A \neq \emptyset$