# When is $A- B = B- A$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Hello I am taking a Discrete Mathematics course and having some trouble with this question about sets:

Under what conditions is $A- B = B- A$

Diagram: [$A- B$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6W0RE.png)

Diagram: [$B- A$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0CZd.png)

Maybe I'm understanding incorrectly, but how can A-B and B-A be equal if they contain elements that are not in each other?

Comment: You're exactly right: **if** they contain elements that are not in each other, they won't be equal :)

Comment: And if $A-B$ and $B-A$ cannot be equal if one contains elements not in the other, what cases are left?

Comment: JFYI: $B\backslash A$ is a more common notation for $B-A$, in case you ever encounter it.

Comment: @TheCount `\setminus` is a more common command to use; it makes the spacing look nicer: $B\setminus A$. Also, using $B-A$ is common enough, I'd say. It's important to be aware of both notations.

Comment: I disagree with the edit that changed the $A-B$ notation to $A \setminus B$, etc.  As much as I dislike the $A-B$ notation, it's perfectly valid and need not be changed.  And as Arthur said it's important to be aware of both.

Comment: @Arthur well that's what I meant, really, was to make the OP aware of the other standard. Thanks for the tip, BTW.

Comment: @tilper agreed.

Comment: @tilper Specifically, writing $B-A$ is not _wrong_ on a site like this, where people gather from all sorts of backgrounds. In a specific class the teacher can decide that one of them is incorrect, but that's not appropriate here.

Comment: No problem, again appears $-$ instead of $\setminus$  also "When" instead of "when".

Comment: See also: [For what conditions on sets $A$ and $B$ the statement $A - B = B - A$ holds?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1909611)

Comment: Presumably, $A-B$ is the relative complement, which might be more easily read if it were $A\setminus B$.  Some clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: It's about sets

Answer (score 4):

If $\color{blue}{A-B=B-A}$

$A\subset B$:
$$A\subset (A-B)\cup B=(B-A)\cup B=(B\cap A')\cup B=B$$
similar way shows $B\subset A$
so $\color{blue}{A=B}$.

contrary is trivial.

Comment: It would have been helpful to say that A and B are **sets** in the first post!

Comment: Change what?  No, I didn't change anything.

Answer (score 2):

If $x\in A-B$, then $x\in A$ but $x\not\in B$. Similarly, if $x\in B-A$, then $x\in B$ but $x\not\in A$; so if $x\in A-B$ and $x\in B-A$, we conclude that $x\in A$ and $x\not\in A$, a contradiction! Hence there exists no such $x$, so $A-B=\emptyset$, so $A\subseteq B$, and similarly $B-A=\emptyset$, so $B\subseteq A$, and therefore $A=B$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $B - A = A -B$.

Claim: $A = B$.

If not, this means there either an $x \in A$ such that $x \notin B$ (and then $x \in A - B$, but $x \notin B - A$, so $A- B \neq B-A$, contradiction), 
or there is an $x \in B$ with $x \notin A$ (and then $x \in B - A$, while $x \notin A - B$, so $A - B \neq B- A$, contradiction again).

So $A = B$ and $A - B = B- A = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a\in A$.

Consider two cases.

1. $a\in A\setminus B$.

Hence, since $A\setminus B=B\setminus A$, we obtain $a\in B$.

2. $a\not\in A\setminus B$.

Thus, $a\not\in A\cap \bar{B}$ or $a\in\bar{A}\cup B$, which says $a\in B$ again.

By the same way we can prove that if $a\in B$ then $a\in A$.

Id est, $A=B$.

Done!